# Why BKDFHash doesn't care about out of range issue?

Tags: c++, hash, hashcode

```
unsigned int BKDRHash(const std::string& str){
unsigned int seed = 131; // 31 131 1313 13131 131313 etc..
unsigned int hash = 0;

for(std::size_t i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
{
    hash = (hash * seed) + str[i];
}

return hash;}
```

Why we don't need to care about if hash goes out of the range of `unsigned int` in the above code? I've seen several example code that did nothing about the overflow problem. Why it still works? What will happen when the value `hash` go out of the range of `unsigned int`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works because overflow doesn't actually happen for `unsigned` integer types per the standard:

> **3.9.1 Fundamental types [basic.fundamental]**
>
> Unsigned integers shall obey the laws of arithmetic modulo 2<sup>n</sup> where n is the
>   number of bits in the value representation of that particular size of
>   integer.<sup>48</sup>
>
> 48. This implies that unsigned arithmetic **does not overflow** because a result that cannot be represented by the resulting
>       unsigned integer type is reduced modulo the number that is one greater than the largest value that can be represented by the resulting unsigned integer type.

Ex: if an `unsigned int` arithmetic result `x` would otherwise exceed `UINT_MAX`, the result is exactly:

```
x % (UINT_MAX+1)
```

thereby leaving you a result within `0...UINT_MAX`